# What can a module do that a superclass cannot (or vice versa)?

Tags: ruby, class, module

I have two classes `Chicken` and `Frog`, which are both subclasses of `Animal`, which contains variables and methods common to both creatures. The subclasses contain modified `initialize` methods, as well as their own instance methods.

At what point, if any, would a module around `Chicken` and `Frog` be useful? Would an `Animal` module replace the `Animal` superclass? In what circumstance, if any, would it be able to?

Answer (score 4):

You can include many modules, but you can have only one superclass. This is quite important distinction. Often it is more convenient to extend functionality through mixins, not inheritance.